# Trying to run app from function and i have an error when i trying to call some variable inside some functinon

Tags: php

Maybe this is simple thing. But I'm so confused. What's going here.

So I had made function which one calling all others files from app.

**load.php**

```
function RunApp(){
   $files = array(
         '/dir/PdoConn.php',
         '/dir/class.php',
         '/dir/function.php',
         '/dir/something.php',
         '/dir/template.php',
         ...);
   foreach ($files as $include){
      $path = MAIN_DIR . $include;
      file_exists($path) ? require_once $path : die();
   }
}
```

Of course in the firsts files, are connection with DB, with `PDO`.

So in some of those files are some `functions`, `classes` etc.

So what's happening, if I try to use `$conn`*(pdo object)* variable in some function.

Let's say:

**function.php**

```
function GetArticle($id){
    global $conn;
    $article = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM article WHERE id = ?");
    $article->execute([$id]);
    return $article;
}
```

*(this function is only example, so do not care about the SQL statement)*

This will throw an error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare()

But if I do in last required file (**/dir/template.php**)

```
print_r(get_defined_vars());
```

It will have this in array:

```
[conn] => PDO Object
```

Of course if I delete whole function `RunApp()` and include those files just from that `foreach`, everything work perfectly.

Comment: `require` will abort the script if the file doesn't exist, you don't need your own `file_exists` test. That's the difference between `require` and `include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files are being required inside your `runapp()` function. So any variables they assign will be local to that function, unless the variables are declared `global`.

So `PdoConn.php` need to have `global $conn;` in it. And all the other files need to declare any global variables they define.

Comment: `PDO` connection is not in the function or in a class. Its a procedural classic code.
[prntscr](http://prntscr.com/oe7bs9)

Comment: But you're including the file inside the `runapp()` function. So everything it does is as if it were inside that function.

Comment: `require` is like copying the code of the other file in place of that statement.

Comment: Thanks for that solution. I just added `global $conn` on the top of  `PdoConn.php` and all works fine.